# Android 4.2 for Asus Transformer tf300t

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I bought an Asus Transformer tf300t tablet. It runs on Android 4.1.

I really need the multi-user feature of the Android 4.2.

I [read](http://www.technobloom.com/android-4-2-will-grace-the-asus-transformer-series/2219547/) that Asus will provide an upgrade for all the Transformer series to Android 4.2, but there isn't any official announcement.

Should I wait for this hypothetical upgrade or install a CyanogenMod ROM right now?

Comment: FYI from the future: the stock ROM is now at 4.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Cyanogen now, and in the event of an official update, go back to the stock Rom.

Steps to install CyanogenMod in Asus TF300t: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_tf300t

Comment: I never install cyanogen, is there any risk ?

Comment: I installed Cyanogen myself many times, and it's very simple. Just follow the steps they provide and remember to backup all the appData you can (Games and other apps).